# Adobe Flex/Action Script - Drop down does not stay put - On opening, it closes immediately

Tags: flash, apache-flex, drop-down-menu, actionscript, adobe

In my Flex/ActionScript application, I have a drop down which is populated dynamically.  On loading the screen which contains this drop down, when I open it, it closes automatically and doesn't stay put.  It seems like the drop down is being redrawn.  But I am not sure.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

I am using Flex 4.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: That's not normal behavior so can you share some of the relevant code that relates to that dropdown? Do you have listeners attached?

Comment: I will post some of my code once I am back to work.